# Android: Open a new layout file on button click and apply SQLite data to it

Tags: android, sqlite, gridview

I have a gridview here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">



    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/topContent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="7">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView0"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="ID: "
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:gravity="center"
            />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:background="@color/purple"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/gridCode"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:gravity="center"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:background="@color/green"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/gridDay"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:gravity="center"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:background="@color/orange"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/gridStart"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:gravity="center"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:background="@color/blue"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/gridDuration"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:gravity="center"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:background="@color/yellow"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/gridType"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:gravity="center"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView6"
            android:background="@color/red"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/gridRoom"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:gravity="center"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridTable"
        android:layout_below="@+id/topContent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dip"
        android:verticalSpacing="15dip"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:gravity="center"

        android:numColumns="7"

        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        >
    </GridView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And a database helper:

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{
    //database information
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME    = "timetable.db";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME       = "timetable_data";

    //the data each column will store
    public static final String COL_1 = "ID";
    public static final String COL_2 = "CODE";
    public static final String COL_3 = "DAY";
    public static final String COL_4 = "START";
    public static final String COL_5 = "DURATION";
    public static final String COL_6 = "TYPE";
    public static final String COL_7 = "ROOM";


    //construct the database
    public DatabaseHelper(Context context)
    {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
    {
        db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,CODE TEXT,DAY TEXT,START TEXT,DURATION TEXT,TYPE TEXT,ROOM TEXT)");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
    {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public boolean insertData(String code, String day, String start, String duration, String type, String room)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COL_2,code);
        contentValues.put(COL_3,day);
        contentValues.put(COL_4,start);
        contentValues.put(COL_5,duration);
        contentValues.put(COL_6,type);
        contentValues.put(COL_7, room);

        long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,contentValues);
        if(result == -1)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }

    public Cursor getAllData()
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor data = db.rawQuery("select * from "+TABLE_NAME,null);
        return data;
    }

    public Integer deleteEntry(String id)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        return db.delete(TABLE_NAME,"ID = ?", new String [] {id});
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to do, is create an adapter that can be applied to that gridview when a button is pressed. The adapter should pull all of the information from the database and insert each bit of data into each cell of the grid. I'd like all of this to happen when a button is pressed, pressing the button will show the grid in a new layout, and when the back button is pressed go back to the main_acitivty layout.
but I'm not sure if I need the other layout file there, or where the button goes, or even if this is possible to do, so any help would be appreciated! thanks!

Main_activity source:

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Adapter;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    DatabaseHelper timetableDB;

    EditText roomInput, codeInput, idInput;
    Spinner dayInput, durationInput, timeInput, sessionInput;
    Button button_add, button_display, button_delete, button_display_grid;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        timetableDB = new DatabaseHelper(this);

        codeInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.codeInput);
        dayInput = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.dayInput);
        timeInput = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.timeInput);
        durationInput = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.durationInput);
        sessionInput = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sessionInput);
        roomInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.roomInput);
        idInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.idInput);

        button_add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_add);
        button_display = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_display);
        button_display_grid = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_display_grid);
        button_delete = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_delete);

        AddData();
        displayData();
        deleteData();
    }

    button_display_grid.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()

    {
        //This method starts the GridView activity when the button is pressed
        @Override
        public void onClick (View v)
        {
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, GridViewActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    }

    public void deleteData()
    {
        button_delete.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v)
                    {
                        Integer deletedData = timetableDB.deleteEntry(idInput.getText().toString());
                        if(deletedData > 0)
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Entry Removed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        else
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error Removing Entry", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
        );
    }
    public void AddData()
    {
        button_add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                boolean isInserted = timetableDB.insertData(
                        codeInput.getText().toString(),
                        dayInput.getSelectedItem().toString(),
                        timeInput.getSelectedItem().toString(),
                        durationInput.getSelectedItem().toString(),
                        sessionInput.getSelectedItem().toString(),
                        roomInput.getText().toString());


                if (isInserted = true)
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Module Added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                else
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error Adding Data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
        );
    }

    public void displayData()
    {
        button_display.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
                {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v)
                    {
                        Cursor data = timetableDB.getAllData();
                        if(data.getCount() == 0)
                        {
                            //show message
                            return;
                        }

                        StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
                        while (data.moveToNext())
                        {
                            buffer.append("ID :"+ data.getString(0)+"\n");
                            buffer.append("Code :"+ data.getString(1)+"\n");
                            buffer.append("Day :"+ data.getString(2)+"\n");
                            buffer.append("Start :"+ data.getString(3)+"\n");
                            buffer.append("Duration: "+ data.getString(4)+"\n");
                            buffer.append("Type :"+ data.getString(5)+"\n");
                            buffer.append("Room :"+ data.getString(6)+"\n\n");
                        }
                    showMessage("My Timetable:", buffer.toString());
                    }
                }
        );
    }
    public void showMessage(String title, String Message)
    {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setCancelable(true);
        builder.setTitle(title);
        builder.setMessage(Message);
        builder.show();
    }
}
```

GridViewActivity.java:

```
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by natha on 17/02/2016.
 *
 * This class gets all of the information in the getAllData() method, adds it to an array list,
 * then an array adapter reads the data from this array list and applies that data to the GridView.
 *
 */
public class GridViewActivity extends MainActivity
{
    private GridView gridTable;
    private ArrayList<String> moduleList;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    private Cursor data;

    DatabaseHelper timetableDB;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     setContentView(R.layout.gridview);

        //GridView
        gridTable=(GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridTable);

        //ArrayList
        moduleList  =   new ArrayList<>();
        adapter     =   new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplicationContext(),
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,moduleList);

        String id, code, day, time, duration, type, room;

        id          =   "";
        code        =   "";
        day         =   "";
        time        =   "";
        duration    =   "";
        type        =   "";
        room        =   "";

        timetableDB = new DatabaseHelper(getBaseContext());//getting the context object

        timetableDB.getAllData();
        try
        {
            //for holding retrieve data from query and store in the form of rows
            Cursor data=timetableDB.getAllData();
            //Move the cursor to the first row.
            if(data.moveToFirst())
            {
                do
                {
                    id          =   data.getString(data.getColumnIndex    ("id"));
                    code        =   data.getString(data.getColumnIndex    ("code"));
                    day         =   data.getString(data.getColumnIndex    ("day"));
                    time        =   data.getString(data.getColumnIndex    ("time"));
                    duration    =   data.getString(data.getColumnIndex    ("duration"));
                    type        =   data.getString(data.getColumnIndex    ("type"));
                    room        =   data.getString(data.getColumnIndex    ("room"));

                    //add in to array list
                    moduleList  .   add(id);
                    moduleList  .   add(code);
                    moduleList  .   add(day);
                    moduleList  .   add(time);
                    moduleList  .   add(duration);
                    moduleList  .   add(type);
                    moduleList  .   add(room);

                    gridTable.setAdapter(adapter);

                }
                while(data.moveToNext());//Move the cursor to the next row.
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "No data found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "No data found "+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        timetableDB.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should move the **button_display_grid.setOnClickListener**, inside the onCreate of your activity, after its initialization.

Comment: So I could do everything I'm trying to in this one class? I don't need to create another?

Comment: I guess that's all you need, since all the other lines are ok.

Comment: Hi Farhad, I don't think it's letting me do that, It's asking for another class when I try to start the intent, or is that not what I should be doing?

Comment: I have not, that was just left in from a previous attempt, I have another app with this solution fully working, however the database structure and handler are completely different so I'm unsure as to what would go in the GridViewActivity

Comment: Sorry I'm confused. So what's the real challenge here ? Add the GridViewActivity and implement the database and other stuff. I don't see the real problem here.

Comment: Sorry, I'm pretty bad at explaining things. When I click the button, I want the data that is currently stored in the database to be displayed in the gridview, which is in a seperate layout file. The only thing is I don't know how to use that data elsewhere

Comment: Added GridViewActivity source code, this class gives me an error saying the data from column -1 (the id field) could not be retrieved

Comment: show the soucecode of the GridViewActivity and other dependent modules. Also, I strongly recommend to open a new question and avoid commenting

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103762/discussion-between-aaranihlus-and-farhad-faghihi).